# Windows-10 network no longer shows Linux machines

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, samba

I have two Windows-10 PCs as well as a small laptop running Lubuntu, and a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian and an Apache LAMP server.  The Windows network no longer shows the Linux machines in the network folder.   I can ping them, and the Raspbian webserver works OK.

**Windows is now version 1809, build 17763.107.**
I have tried all sorts of Samba configs- currently, the Raspberry is using

```
[USBDrive]     
 comment = The 32Gb USB data  drive     
 path = /media/USBDATA32      
 force user = aqk     
 guest ok = no      
 create mask = 0775      
 directory mask = 0775     
 browseable = yes      
; public = yes      
 read only = no
```

I suspect this is more of a Windows problem that Linux or Samba.  A while back there was no problem with the share.

Answer (score 0):

You Samba is probably using the vulnerable SMB protocol version 1, which
was disabled in Windows 10 as a security measure.

From the article
[How to configure Samba to use SMBv2 and disable SMBv1 on Linux or Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-samba-to-use-smbv2-and-disable-smbv1-on-linux-or-unix/) :

- Edit the `smb.conf` file, run:

  ```
  sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
  ```
- Find the `[global]` section and append the following line:

  ```
  min protocol = SMB2
  ```

  An alternative configuration line is:

  ```
  protocol = SMB2
  ```
- Save and close the file.
- Restart the samba server by one of the following commands (depending
  on the Linux distribution) :

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart smb.service
  sudo systemctl restart smbd.service
  ```

Comment: Tried the above switching Samba to SMB2, and still the Rasbian machine is not visible.  Yet I can run the Apache webserver index.php from a windows machine, and I can ping the Rasp machine. But if type \\RASP3B  into a Windows webbrowser,      it says "Windows can not access - The device or resource (RASP3B) is not set up to accept connections on port "The File and printer sharing (SMB)".

Comment: ADDENDUM- The Network Discovery Method on the Windows machines is "WSD", not Netbios.  Is there possibly some parameter in the Samba  smb.conf  that should reflect this?

Comment: ADDENDUM#2 - It seems that WSD support in Samba is still a work in progress. From what I can see, it's preferable at present to continue using the old and obsolescent NetBios for discovering Linux machines on a Windows network.  But- is NetBios compatible with SMB2 and up?

Comment: These are two different things. SMBv1 could run over NetBIOS, but SMBv2 only runs over TCP. But nothing prevents them both. You could also [Enable SMBv1](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-access-files-network-devices-using-smbv1-windows-10). This isn't extremely dangerous, since for the vulnerability to be exploited one of the computers on the network must already be infected.

Answer (score 0):

For me the below worked. It did not show the server in the Windows folder but it did allow me to map the drives and see them from there.

Edit the `smb.conf` file, run:

```
sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Find the `[global]` section and append the following lines:

```
min protocol = SMB2
protocol = SMB2
```

Thanks to harrymc